# Initialising Knockout checkbox value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I think this may be more of a language problem as opposed to a framework issue, but here goes:

I'm having trouble setting the initial value of a checkbox.

Ive added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8ppQ/)

Thanks!

Here is the troublesome code:

```
var allPrices = [
        { month: 'January', prices: [ (3, true), (4, false), (4, false), (4, false)] },
        { month: 'February', prices: [(3, true), (4, false), (4, false), (4, false)] },
        { month: 'March', prices: [(3, true), (4, false), (4, false), (4, false)] }
    ]        

//--Page ViewModel
var id = 1;

//--Set the structure for the basic price object
function Price(quote, isChecked) {
    this.quote = ko.observable(quote);
    this.valid = true;
    if (isNaN(quote)) {
        this.valid = false;
    }
    this.selected = ko.observable(isChecked);
    this.id = id;
    id++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the syntax `(3, true)` you are using the [Comma Operator](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/) and not creating an object.

The comma operator evaluates to its second argument (in this case to `true`) so it does not create an object with the value 3 and true as you would have been probably expected.

You need use the `{}` to create an object and you also need some property names, so you need to rewrite your prices to:

```
prices: [ 
    { quote: 3, isChecked: true}, 
    { quote: 4, isChecked: false}, 
    { quote: 4, isChecked: false}, 
    { quote: 4, isChecked: false} ]
```

And you need to change prices creation to

```
this.prices = ko.utils.arrayMap(prices, function (item) { 
     return new Price(item.quote, item.isChecked); 
 });
```

becase the callback function of the `arrayMap` takes on argument: the current item, and you can access the `quote` and `isChecked` from that current item.

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JmLuT/1/)

Comment: That's great- thanks a lot for that. I had tried the {quote:, ischecked:} declaration before but it didn't work as I hadn't fully understood the change prices creation part until now.